# Sign in and access school onedrive files through nodejs, without signing in graphically

Tags: node.js, heroku, onedrive, headless

I am looking to sign in and access my school onedrive files through a nodejs heroku server for a project. I need to download and parse an excel file that has been shared with me from my school onedrive and parse it in the heroku nodejs server. This server will have requests made to it by my website, which uses the excel file as a table of dates for events. I don't want to change the usage of this shared excel file because it is owned by someone else who manages the contents.

Basically:
I'm wondering how a headless server such as nodejs running on heroku can sign in and access files for a single, constant user (I think I'm fine with storing my password in a database on heroku securely)

I've already gotten my app a client id token, but I can't seem to get around the fact that the user has to log in through a pop-up window.

Comment: Use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) - A Headless Chrome Node API. That will allow you to navigate like you do on a normal browser

Comment: I'd suggest you explore the [One Drive API options for node.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs+onedrive+api).  I think you'd rather just use the API than try to pretend you're a browser.

Comment: Thanks! that's an interesting thought @molamk, but afaik that wouldn't be able to run on a heroku nodejs server - please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00, I've looked into this but it requires and 'accesstoken' which I think I need to use the sign-in pop-up to get - is there another way to get an access token programatically?

Comment: Of course it can. If your interactions are UI intensive that's a good option. If you're just communicating with OneDrive, then their API is the way to go

Comment: correction @molamk I still need to look into this more but the google seem sto indicate some people have done it: [link](https://timleland.com/headless-chrome-on-heroku/) - edit: didn't see the post you made there, sorry.